# Create a new column of cumulative value based on multiple columns in data table

Tags: r, data.table

This is my first post after days of searching for answer. I'm transitioning from R data frame to R data table with difficulties.

What I want to achieve is to create some sort of cumulative value based on the indicator from multiple columns/variables.

I can do that quite easily with data frame:

```
DF = data.frame(
a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
a2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
a3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA) 
)

DF$b1<-as.numeric(0)

for(i in 1:3) {
DF$b1<-as.numeric(DF[i]>0)+DF$b1
}
```

However, to me, it is not so straight forward in data table. What I have done is the following:

```
DT<-setDT(DF)

DT[,b1:= as.numeric(DT[,1]>0)+as.numeric(DT[,2]>0)+as.numeric(DT[,3]>0)]
```

The code above works.  But it doesn't seem to be user friendly if I want to increase the number of columns analyzed to (say) 10.  In the case of data frame, I can just change the index from 1:3 to 1:10.

Appreciate any comments on how I can improve the code for data table above.  It would also be very helpful if any good resources or documentations can be shared with me on this type of practical problem:  referencing column index in a loop for data table.  Thanks.

Comment: You can still use loops on `data.table`s: `DT$b1 <- as.numeric(DT[[i]] > 0) + DT$b1`

Comment: @sindri_baldur Thanks!  But since this version of the code invoke $, I am just curious if it will be as fast as the version that uses .SD if the data table contains million of rows.

Comment: In that case I would expect the `.SD` solution to be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `rowSums` after turning you table to logical via `.SD > 0`, i.e.

```
DT[, b1 := rowSums(.SD > 0)][]

#   a1 a2 a3 b1
#1:  1  1  1  3
#2:  2  2  2  3
#3:  3  3  3  3
#4:  4  4  4  3
#5:  5  5 NA NA
```

Comment: Very nice solution and `.SDCols` can be added to control the required columns easily as needed.